# Amazon List order product is not displaying in by MWS?

Tags: amazon-mws

I am working on Amazon MWS for importing all amazon orders in our internal database. I am able to import all orders in my database  by php and mysql but not get orders product.

Comment: We need more information than just two lines, and please accept more answers to some of your previous questions otherwise no1 will bother helping you

Answer (score 0):

I you can import your orders. It mean you've got the `AmazonOrderId` in your database.

Use the example `/src/MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Samples/ListOrderItemsSample.php` from the [Orders API PHP Client Library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/orders/orders/v20110101/php.html/185-9116211-9356539) to get the products from your `AmazonOrderId`